# How to get the comments of a JIRA issue in a custom release note template

Tags: jira

We upgraded our jira to version 5.0.5 today, before we were running version 4.2.4. In that version we had made a custom release notes template that would also show all comments made on an issue. To do that we had to be able to get a `CommentManager` object. We did this like this:

```
#foreach ($issue in $issueType.issues)
#if($issueType.issues.size() > 0)
    #set ($comments = $action.ComponentManager.CommentManager.getComments($issue))
    #if ($comments) 
       #foreach ($comment in $comments)
...
```

That worked fine in JIRA 4.2.4 however it isn't working anymore in jira 5.0.5, does anyone know how i can get a CommentManager object again when creating a custom release notes template in JIRA 5.0.5 or how to get a CommentManager object some other way, without using `$action` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your vm template, write this:

```
#set ($componentAccessorClass        = $constantsManager.getClass().getClassLoader().findClass('com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor'))
#set ($componentAccessorConstructor  = $componentAccessorClass.getConstructor())
#set ($componentAccessor             = $componentAccessorConstructor.newInstance())
```

Now you have access to the [Component Accessor](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/component/ComponentAccessor.html) which can get you pretty much anything you want, including the Comment Manager.

Now, all you have to do is call getCommentManager() on your Component Accessor variable.

```
#set($commentManager = $componentAccessor.getCommentManager() )
```

Hope that helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

JiraWebActionSupport has the following deprecated method that provided the component manager object.

`@Deprecated
    public ComponentManager getComponentManager()
    {
        return ComponentManager.getInstance();
    }`

and https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+Custom+Release+Notes+Template+Containing+Release+Comments
has some Velocity code but looking at the 5.0.1 source it looks like Velocity is no longer being used?

I would file an Improvement at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA to add a getCommentManager method to JiraWebActionSupport.java

Comment: hi thanks for your answers, the links your pointing to is how to add a customn field for a comment on the release notes but not on how to get the comments of the issues of inside the release notes. The GetComponentManager method is what i used to use but this no longer seems to work. However i did find another way that works with jira 5.0.5 it's a bit of a deviation but i managed to get a component manager object and the rest is simple. I'll post my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

this is the way i used in jira to get a componentmanager object, once you have the componentmanager object it's rather easy to do the rest:

```
#set ($componentManagerClass = $constantsManager.getClass().getClassLoader().findClass('com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager'))
#set ($method = $componentManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod('getInstance', null))
#set ($componentManager = $method.invoke(null, null))
```

i'm using this solution now, and it can be rather helpfull to others to almost get any kind of class using the constantsmanager.